# Can you assign the result from a SQL Query as the name of a file?

Tags: sql, powershell, sqlcmd

This code creates a `C:\DestinationFolder\MyQuery.txt` file which stores the Database version info (e.g. 11.0.3128.0):

```
Declare @Cmd Varchar(6000)
Declare @Query Varchar(2000)

Set @Query = 'Select SERVERPROPERTY(''ProductVersion'')'
Set @cmd = 'bcp "' + @Query + '" queryout ' + 'C:\DestinationFolder\MyQuery.txt' + ' -c -T -t'
Exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Would be possible to modify above code, so that the newly created file will be named after the query results? (e.g 11.0.3128.0.txt)

My goal is to be able to run a query and store the result as the filename.

Answer (score 1):

No need to execute any queries at all - you can do this strictly through PowerShell & the SMO objects.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-Null;
$MySQLObject = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server "myservername";
$VersionNumber = $MySQLObject.Information.VersionString;
$MyFileName = "C:\DestinationFolder\$VersionNumber.txt";
Add-Content $MyFileName $VersionNumber
```

See http://sqlmag.com/powershell/using-sql-server-management-objects-powershell

Comment: Great!! It worked.   Note: I had some issue with configuring SMO due to the following error "Could not load file or assembly ‘Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=9.0.242.0,..." resolved the problem following this article http://www.maxtblog.com/2011/07/sql-server-smo-loading-assemblies-gotcha%E2%80%99s/